How do I perform moderation analysis in Lavaan?
I want to perform two moderations in this model using lavaan :
model_1 <- "  # Measurement Model
attitude =~ 45.probu + 46.probu + 47.probu+ 50.probu
perceived_control =~ 127.EXPECTATION1 + 128.EXPECTATION2 + 129.EXPECTATION3
subjective_norms =~ 126.TEMPTATION1+126.TEMPTATION2 + 126.TEMPTATION3 + 126.TEMPTATION4
intention =~  132.WILLINGNESS1 + 133.WILLINGNESS2 + 134.WILLINGNESS3 +134.WILLINGNESS3
cyberbullying =~ 91.CYB_BU+ 92.CYB_BU+93.CYB_BU +  94.CYB_BU+  96.CYB_BU+ 100.CYB_BU  + 102.CYB_BU
regressions
intention ~ attitude + subjective_norms + perceived_control
cyberbullying ~ intention
"
I am trying to test the moderation effect of perceived_control on intention and cybebrullying (perceived_controlintention & perceived_controlcybebrulliyng)
I have tried with inProd from semtools but is semms like I'm doing domething wrong.
